# Woocommerce: change admin interface font color to black

Tags: css, woocommerce, colors, admin

We just launched a WooCommerce store and admin has a grey font that is against ADA (Americans with Disablities Act). Companies are getting sued for not being compliant.

Anyway, how can all the light grey fonts be changed to black in the admin interface?
I noticed not all the grey fonts use the same color:#______ code, either.

Child-theme/assets/css/admin-styles.css was added but that doesn't work, even using !important. Here is part of it.

```
/* CSS Document */
#order_data p {
color: black !important;
}
```

Also tried was adding the <style...</style> to a custom plugin

```
add_filter( 'admin_bar_menu', 'do_stuff', 25 );
function do_stuff( $wp_admin_bar ) {
    echo '<style>
    table.widefat td,
    table.widefat th (and more styles)
    </style>';
}
```

But, there are numerous classes to enter to capture all text that should be black.

Is there a better way to change the font colors to black in admin? All except those that should be color like red or links or other fonts that should be a different color to stand out? Like the left menu that has a dark background and light fonts should be used.

Thank you.

Comment: This is wrong hook to use. Read this https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Admin_Themes